# Testing a race condition in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I wanted to test a race condition in Phoenix (for example, when inserting two records at a same time that handles some sequence generation without conflicts), what would be the best way to handle this?

How can I ensure I get a collision?

Answer (score 0):

You're a glutton for punishment, my friend.

Unfortunately, there aren't tools to reproduce race conditions Erlang, let alone most languages. The closest you'll typically get is with detection software like [Helgrind for C/C++](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) and [Chess for C#/C++](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/).

Follow [this advice from the Programming StackExchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196110/51694):

> There's no good general way to trigger a race condition in testing.
>
> Your ONLY hope is to design them completely out of your system.
>
> When and if you find that someone else has stuffed one in, you should
>   stake him out an anthill, and then redesign to eliminate it. After you
>   have designed his faux pas (pronounced f***up) out of your system, you
>   can go release him from the ants. (If the ants have already consumed
>   him, leaving only bones, put up a sign saying "This is what happens to
>   people who put race conditions into XYZ project!" and LEAVE HIM
>   THERE.)

Comment: So it's unrealistic even to expect spinning up something like a bunch of `Task.async` and hoping that some conflict?

Comment: Yes. You're better of figuring out how you can design your system to prevent those conditions from ever happening in the first place.